# (Eclipse RCP) How can I get the reference of Editor in command handler

Tags: eclipse, rcp

I'd like the get the text of editor in a command handler, so how can I get the reference of Editor, thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

to get the referece of the editor in a command handler you could do this:

```
public class myCommandHandler extends AbstractHandler implements IHandler {

    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
        Shell shell = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(event).getShell();
        IWorkbenchPage page = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(event).getActivePage();
        IEditorInput editorInput = page.getActiveEditor().getEditorInput();
...
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void setEnabled(Object evaluationContext) {
    Object editor = ((EvaluationContext)evaluationContext).getParent().getVariable("activeEditor");
```

Then you type cast so combining with above answer now execute and enabling both shall work.